# receiver's address from sender's address and txid

Tags: transactions

I want to trace a transaction. I have both the sender's btc address and the txid. How can I find out the recipient address of the transaction?

Comment: Go to a block explorer, like mempool.space or blockstream.info and paste the txid, you'll see all recipient's addresses there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is blockchain.com the only place where you can see the blockchain?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98426/is-blockchain-com-the-only-place-where-you-can-see-the-blockchain)